# How to compute tangent and bitangent vectors

Tags: textures, glsl, uv-mapping, three.js

I have a texture loaded in three.js, then passed to the shaders. In the vertex shader I compute the normal, and I save into a variable the uv vector.

```
<script id="vertexShader" type="x-shader/x-vertex">

                varying vec3 N,P;
                varying vec2 UV;

                void main() {
                    gl_Position= projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
                    P= position;
                    N= normalMatrix * vec3(normal);
                    UV= uv;
                }
            </script>
            <script id="fragmentShader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">

                varying vec3 N,P;
                varying vec2 UV;
                uniform sampler2D texture;

                void main() {
                    gl_FragColor= texture2D(texture,UV);
                }

            </script>
```

How do I compute the T and B vectors?

Comment: do you want the algorithm in general or specifically for your library of choice ?

Comment: If I can compute it with three.js it would be better.

Comment: You may want to look up the [MikkTSpace algorithm](https://github.com/mmikk/MikkTSpace), which is a standardised way of generating a tangent basis that's designed to inter-operate well between different software packages.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

First of all, for every 3D vertex there is infinite tangent and bi-tangent vectors. The below image explains why there is an infinite number of tangent spaces for each vertex, the tangent and bitangent can have any direction in the shown plane.

[image: Infinite number of tangent spaces for each vertex]

So in order to properly calculate the most useful<sup>1</sup> tangent space, we want our tangent space to be aligned such that the x axis (the tangent) corresponds to the u direction in the bump map and the y axis (bitangent) corresponds to the v direction in the bump map, we should already have normal of the vertex which already corresponds to the Z direction in tangent space.

<sub>(1) most useful because in the end we want normal vectors to be sampled from the texture</sub>

That best be explained with pictures, we want our [tangent space](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/63832/normals-vs-normal-maps/63833#63833) to be aligned like `(u, v)` shown below.

[image]

[Source of the image though not strictly related to computer graphics](http://www.sedris.org/stc/2004/tu/srm/)

In computer graphics developers usually use `(u,v)` also known as texture coordinates.
We will assume T is the tangent and B is the bitangent, and `P0` is our target vertex, that is part of the triangle `(P0,P1,P2)`.

First remember what we wanted to do, is to calculate tangent and bitanget that:

1. T aligned with u and B aligned with v.
2. T and B lays in the plane with the vertex normal (the plane shown in the above image).

The point is we already assumed that T and B lays in the same plane and corresponds to U and V now if we can know their values we  can cross product and the third vector to construct a transformation matrix from world to tangent space.

[image]

Given that we know that any 2D vector can be written as a linear combination of two independent vectors<sup>2</sup> and since we already have the triangle points (edges), shown in the above image. We can write:

> E1 = (u1-u0)T + (v1-v0)B
>
> E2 = (u2-u0)T + (v2-v0)B

<sub>(2) actually that's is how basis matrix is derived</sub>

The above equation can be written in a matrix form,

```
| E1x E1y E1z |   | deltaU1 deltaV1 | * | Tx Ty Tz |
| E2x E2y E2z | = | deltaU2 deltaV2 |   | Bx By Bz |
```

By solving the matrixs equation we can determine T and B values we can construct a transformation matrix.

The full source code in C++

```
#include "Vector4D.h"


struct Triangle
{
    unsigned short  index[3];
};


void CalculateTangentArray(long vertexCount, const Point3D *vertex, const Vector3D *normal,
        const Point2D *texcoord, long triangleCount, const Triangle *triangle, Vector4D *tangent)
{
    Vector3D *tan1 = new Vector3D[vertexCount * 2];
    Vector3D *tan2 = tan1 + vertexCount;
    ZeroMemory(tan1, vertexCount * sizeof(Vector3D) * 2);
    
    for (long a = 0; a < triangleCount; a++)
    {
        long i1 = triangle->index[0];
        long i2 = triangle->index[1];
        long i3 = triangle->index[2];
        
        const Point3D& v1 = vertex[i1];
        const Point3D& v2 = vertex[i2];
        const Point3D& v3 = vertex[i3];
        
        const Point2D& w1 = texcoord[i1];
        const Point2D& w2 = texcoord[i2];
        const Point2D& w3 = texcoord[i3];
        
        float x1 = v2.x - v1.x;
        float x2 = v3.x - v1.x;
        float y1 = v2.y - v1.y;
        float y2 = v3.y - v1.y;
        float z1 = v2.z - v1.z;
        float z2 = v3.z - v1.z;
        
        float s1 = w2.x - w1.x;
        float s2 = w3.x - w1.x;
        float t1 = w2.y - w1.y;
        float t2 = w3.y - w1.y;
        
        float r = 1.0F / (s1 * t2 - s2 * t1);
        Vector3D sdir((t2 * x1 - t1 * x2) * r, (t2 * y1 - t1 * y2) * r,
                (t2 * z1 - t1 * z2) * r);
        Vector3D tdir((s1 * x2 - s2 * x1) * r, (s1 * y2 - s2 * y1) * r,
                (s1 * z2 - s2 * z1) * r);
        
        tan1[i1] += sdir;
        tan1[i2] += sdir;
        tan1[i3] += sdir;
        
        tan2[i1] += tdir;
        tan2[i2] += tdir;
        tan2[i3] += tdir;
        
        triangle++;
    }
    
    for (long a = 0; a < vertexCount; a++)
    {
        const Vector3D& n = normal[a];
        const Vector3D& t = tan1[a];
        
        // Gram-Schmidt orthogonalize
        tangent[a] = (t - n * Dot(n, t)).Normalize();
        
        // Calculate handedness
        tangent[a].w = (Dot(Cross(n, t), tan2[a]) < 0.0F) ? -1.0F : 1.0F;
    }
    
    delete[] tan1;
}
```

Full source code and derivation can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20110708081637/http://www.terathon.com/code/tangent.html).

Comment: What if I don't have a triangle? In my case I have a texture that should be applied on a sphere. How to adapt it to this case?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri isn't the sphere build from triangles? You just loop over the vertices like in the code. If your sphere isn't triangle based that's a totally different story.

Comment: I'm using three.js SphereGeometry (in javascript). Maybe I should pass the face property to the shaders? The sphere I draw has 1089 vertices and 1084 faces.

Comment: you calculate tangent space and then pass the tangents to the shaders. And you should have access to face/vertices in order to calculate tangent space.

Comment: In my case I'll have 1084 tangents, how do I map the tangents with the vertices?

Comment: each vertex will have a tangent a bitangent. You can either have 3 arrays. array for vertices and array for tangents etc or use one array where tangents and bitangent and veritces interleave

Comment: Sorry but I still haven't understood a thing. After I compute the tangents and have this array to pass to shaders, how do I associate each TBN space with the vertices? Do I have to calculate inside which face is each vertex?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri the vertex shader is executed once per vertex. You calculate the TBN for each vertex in the vertex shader.

Comment: @concept3d I don't understand why one needs to do so many calculations for tangents.I mean,looks here https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-Lighting/Normal-Mapping   ,that's much simpler. What is the benefit to do it this way?

Comment: @MichaelIvanov I didn't follow the steps in the link, but it looks similar to me

Comment: @concept3d handedness, is it mandatory?

Comment: @Michael IV  I believe this is one of the easiest approaches.  This solution is consistent with your learnopengl link (look for "Tangent space" section). Another approach is calculating TBN in shader : https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86530/is-it-possible-to-calculate-the-tbn-matrix-in-the-fragment-shader .